# NPE in TabSpec, from Fragment dealing with TabHost/TabWidget

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop a tabbed view with TabHost / TabWidget for Android 4.2.1 (target is Samsung Galaxy Tab 2) API level 16.

Since **TabActivity is deprecated**, I don't find samples easily.

The Application terminates with a NPE:

```
07-30 15:30:04.617: E/AndroidRuntime(18526): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 15:30:04.617: E/AndroidRuntime(18526): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 15:30:04.617: E/AndroidRuntime(18526):    at android.widget.TabHost$ViewIdContentStrategy.<init>(TabHost.java:640)
07-30 15:30:04.617: E/AndroidRuntime(18526):    at android.widget.TabHost$ViewIdContentStrategy.<init>(TabHost.java:635)
07-30 15:30:04.617: E/AndroidRuntime(18526):    at android.widget.TabHost$TabSpec.setContent(TabHost.java:484)
07-30 15:30:04.617: E/AndroidRuntime(18526):    at fr.lfinance.crm.ProspectDetailFragment.onCreateView(ProspectDetailFragment.java:53)
```

The code of the fragment:

```
public class ProspectDetailFragment extends Fragment {

   [...]

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(
      LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup      container,
      Bundle         savedInstanceState )
   {
      final View rootView =
         inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_prospect_detail,container,false);
      if( _prospect != null ) {
         final TabHost tabHost =
            (TabHost)rootView.findViewById( R.id.prospect_detail );

         final TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec( "rawdatatab" );
         tabSpec.setIndicator("Données brutes" );
         tabSpec.setContent( R.id.rawdata ); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE IS NPE
         tabHost.addTab( tabSpec );

         final GridView gvw = (GridView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.rawdata );
         final List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(2*_properties.size());
         for( final String[] pair : _properties ) {
            lst.add( pair[0] );
            lst.add( pair[1] );
         }
         final ArrayAdapter< String > adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter< String >(
               getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst );
         gvw.setAdapter( adapter );

         [... adding 3 others tabs]

      }
      return rootView;
   }
}
```

The file `rawdata.xml`:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:id="@+id/rawdata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProspectDetailFragment" />
```

The file `fragment_prospect_detail.xml`:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/prospect_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

The file `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fr.lfinance.crm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="fr.lfinance.crm.ProspectListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="fr.lfinance.crm.ProspectDetailActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ProspectListActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ProspectListActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**How can I set up a TabSpec to avoid such NPE?**

Comment: Did you cover these steps: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/tabs.html#example I don't seem to be able to find the cause of this, but let me check again.

Comment: I think also, that your `Activity` should extend `TabActivity`. **EDIT** or this falls below the deprecation ?

Comment: Something else I could have thought of - paste the manifest here too.

Comment: I think you should add each tab as a separate Activity in the manifest like: `<activity android:name=".Tab1" />` - is this codeable?

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those things that we omit quite often, see if it helps you. If not, get back here and we'll think of something :)

Comment: The tutorial is obsolete, it rely on TabActivity which is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours searching, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730259/android-tabbed-layout-setcontent?answertab=active#tab-top) on SO.

Well done! Here is `fragment_prospect_detail.xml`, amended:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/prospect_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <include layout="@layout/fragment_rawdata" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

It lacks only one line `<include layout="@layout/fragment_rawdata" />`...

I have added `tabHost.setup();` in `ProspectDetailFragment.onCreateView()`, too.

I know I'll be back with another questions... A lot !